# Splunk: How to extract a field containing spaces

Tags: regex, splunk

I try to extact the value of a field that contains spaces. Appearently it is hard to find a regular expression for this case (even the question is if it is possible at all).

Example: Log bla message=hello world next=some-value bla

Since Splunk uses a space to determine the next field to start this is quite a challenge.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Its ok. I did not know that I can find a pattern and extract only a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
| rex field=_raw "message=(?<message>.*?)\s*\w*="
```

The above will capture everything after =, until the start of the whitespace before the keyword before the next =.

If it is possible that message will be the last keyword, then use this...

```
| rex field=_raw "message=(?<message>.*?)\s*(\w*=|$)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In splunk you can use groups to find and I identify a longer pattern but only use a part of it to combine those.

The pattern looks like .*(?Ppatternforfield).*. It might not be syntactical correct but it is the way it looks like. You can use the extractor providing sample values to give you a similar construction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put in double quotes , PFB example:

```
host="pets" punct=* "Pet name"="BAMBOO"
```

In above search command **Pet name** is a interesting field identified by splunk